# akka.net how do you get actors to return ONE version of the truth, high message scenario

Tags: concurrency, architecture, akka.net

how do you create a system where you have a many-to-one truth scenario?

imagine i have an object with state that changes based on events and I need MANY, 1000,10000, million other actors to read such data (or request it via message) concurrently 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could broadcast the state change to the interested actors, and they could update their own copies of the state?
It would require them to be restricted to only updating the state in response to a "state update" message.